# prevent parent resize while mouse hovering a child

Tags: html, css

hover items and you'll see the `wrap` will resize hovering on second title.

How to prevent this?

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrap{
position:fixed;
min-width:140px;
}

.title{
padding:3px 25px 3px 9px;
background:gold;
}

.title:hover{
border-right:10px solid lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>loremxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a transparent border, and then change the border-color on hover instead.

`.title { border-right:10px solid transparent; }`

`.title:hover { border-color:lightseagreen; }`

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrap{
position:fixed;
min-width:140px;
}

.title{
padding:3px 25px 3px 9px;
min-width:30%;
background:gold;
border-right:10px solid transparent;
}

.title:hover{
border-color:lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>loremxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

best n easy solution will be just apply the border of `title` with color as transparent and then on hover change the color of border.

check the below

```
.title{
 ..
 ..
 border-right:10px solid transparent;
 ..
}

.title:hover{
 border-right-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrap{
position:fixed;
min-width:140px;
}

.title{
padding:3px 25px 3px 9px;
min-width:30%;
background:gold;
margin-right:15px;
border-right:10px solid transparent;
}

.title:hover{
border-right-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>loremxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, seconds difference 

Answer (score 0):

Increase the minimum width of `.wrap` to be greater than the longest string inside.
For example, I set it to 250px.

```css
.wrap{
position:fixed;
min-width:250px;
}

.title{
padding:3px 25px 3px 9px;
min-width:30%;
background:gold;
}

.title:hover{
border-right:10px solid lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>loremxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```